# Xcode: Easiest Way To Send Data From iOS TextField For Example To A Remote Database

Tags: mysql, xcode, ios4, textfield

I currently have an online web hosted MySQL database with HostGator.com that currently stores user sign ups for a service of mine. Currently, the only way to store information in that database is from my online form on a website.

My goal is to replicate that form on an iOS app by using textfields etc. What I need help figuring out is, how can I take the data input from the user on the iOS app, and send that information to the MySQL database. From what I found, there is no way to go from iOS straight to MySQL, so I would need to use PHP as well. However, how do I get that data from the iOS app to PHP so that I can send the data from PHP to the MySQL database? As well as, how I can I do the vice versa, meaning, if I wanted, how can I send a message back from PHP to the iOS app?

I have heard people suggest SQLite, but that appears to be a local database on the iOS which I do not need. I do not want to store anything locally on the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just gather the data from a native form, then use a NSURLRequest / NSURLConnection to send the data to your php server page.

```
//Example form with one php variable only. Use get URL argument notation to add more args.
NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var=%@",textBox.text];
NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/script.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
```

Comment: Question and just FYI I'm a novice Xcode user. The code you provided is has no errors but would it be necessary to use Alloc when creating NSURLs, NSData, etc.? How about if this code was put into a method, would it need it then? I just want to write code correctly so I'm looking for some direction. Thanks

Comment: You do not need to use alloc / init if you use the code above. However do note that if you need to assign them to an instance variable (class variable) you have to retain them (i.e. take ownership) first.