# How to update a MySQL Database with UITextField content in Xcode 5?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, json

I'm building my first iPhone application which pulls clients network information from a MySQL database and displays the content in UITextFields. This is all working fine, the correct information is pulled down and the client name added to a UITableView, then when the client name is selected a segue is performed that moves to the second view controller where the text fields are populated with the rest of the clients information.

This is the PHP code used to get this working;

```
<?php

$ipaddress = $_GET['ipaddress'];
$netpass = $_GET['netpass'];
$wifipass = $_GET['wifipass'];
$domain = $_GET['domain'];
$name = $_GET['name'];


 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","drift","Drift","drift"    );
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "UPDATE networks SET Ip='$ipaddress', Domain='$domain', Wifi='$wifipass',     Password='$netpass$  WHERE Name = '$name'";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);


$result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM networks");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

(I used this tutorial to get as far as I have so far 
http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/ 
If any more information is needed with regards to the coding of the app itself this can be found in the above link, I have no idea which parts of the existing code you may need to see in order to assist as I am completely new to Php, MySQL and JSON.)

Now, what I want to do is make it so that the information which has been pulled from the mysql database and displayed in the UITExtFields can be edited and then saved back to the database (to update existing records only not to add new records). I've looked around but I just can't find a solution that shows the required PHP and how to then use the PHP file in Xcode to update the MySQL data.

I've nearly got the PHP side working, I have managed to create a script that updates the database from a web form so what I really need is is to know how to pass the value of UITextField.text to the php file instead of the value of the web form?

I can post the update form I have if it will help?

Thanks for your time, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update 2:

```
     NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/updatedb.php?name=%@&ipaddress=%@&netpass=%@&wifipass=%@&domain=%@", schoolnameField.text, ipaddressField.text, _netpassField.text,_wifipassField.text,_domainField.text];

// build the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *body= [NSMutableData data];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// getting answer from the server.
// you can echo message from the server let's say :"Update finish" or something like     that...
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request     returningResponse:NULL error:nil];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"returned: %@", returnString);
```

Comment: You're probably going to want to authenticate the user with some credentials (username and password), and you can do a POST in iOS with [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutableurlrequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @MarcusAdams I have had a look at the NSMutableURLRequest documentation and it certainly looks hopeful.
I've also found this post which is very close to what i'm looking for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509419/xcode-easiest-way-to-send-data-from-ios-textfield-for-example-to-a-remote-datab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you want to update address of your user...
you recognise the user by userID: so you send the records you want to update via Xcode with POST
objective-C code:

```
- (void)updateDataBase
{

NSString *name = @"name";// this is the name for to find the correct record.

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.domain.com/file.php?name=%@&ipaddress=%@&schoolname=%@&netpass=%@&wifipass=%@&domain=%@&server=%@", name, ipaddressField.text, schoolnameField.text, netpassField.text,wifipassField.text,domainField.text, serverField.text];

// build the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *body= [NSMutableData data];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// getting answer from the server.
// you can echo message from the server let's say :"Update finish" or something like that...
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:nil];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"returned: %@", returnString);

}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$ipaddress = $_GET['ipaddress'];
$schoolname = $_GET['schoolname'];
$netpass = $_GET['netpass'];
$wifipass = $_GET['wifipass'];
$domain = $_GET['domain'];
$server = $_GET['server'];
$name = $_GET['name'];


$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass, $mysql_db);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "UPDATE networks SET Ip='$ipaddress', Domain='$domain', Server='$server', Wifi='$wifipass',  WHERE name = '$name'";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);


$result = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM users");

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Hop it's helping you :)

Comment: @user3613006 please check if its helping you

Comment: Why? it's weird i'm using the same code with my app and its working great let me check it again maybe i'll make it simpler

Comment: @user3613006 Sorry i made mistake in the php script, now its fixed, check it now please... i wrote it yesterday from my memory, now i checked my php script, anyway that should work, please let me know if you success!! :)

Comment: @user3613006 JSON if object in (looks like XML) that you can retrieve your data from your server get it as one long string then parsing it into your code to objects, its very very easy and very recommended to use with server connections and APPs

Comment: @user3613006 hehehe i changed again the code because i forget to change it to our example names, now is ok, changing address for user ID

Comment: @user3613006 give me your real column names and i make the php for you and the Xcode

Comment: @DrifterJim Ok so i update the files to match your DB, please take a look on the code to see i don't have typo there.

Comment: There must be something else stopping this from working somewhere? Xcode detected an error with your script - an extra '}' - this error went when I removed it - So it's obviously communicating O.K?

Comment: just delete the } after the $result line :)

Comment: i really don't know what going wrong there because i made table with your exactly columns names and its work perfect

Comment: @DrifterJim if you want me to check it on your server you can login to your server and after that make TeamViewer with me and i'll try fix it for you more then that  I'm sorry i can't see what is wrong on your case :), if you want my idea of team viewer solution, add me on Skype: dekelm8

Comment: Perhaps it's MySQL that's the problem, what version are you using? What version php are you running too?

Comment: It was the version of PHP or MySQL I was running causing the problems, I installed MAMP and set up a new table and it works fine with exactly the same code!

Comment: Cool :) happy that's helped you :) please also vote up if its help you ;)